# Get State function from a Service Block?

Tags: anylogic

Is there a function to get the state from a service Block? I mean the state Busy, Idle ? I want to build a Gantt CHart. I've tried with the RessourcePools, but thats not what i want. I want the states from the Machines(Service-Blocks). If theres any function, can someone share the code?

Answer (score 1):

### code-complete

First, you can always find all possible methods on blocks by using code-complete:
[image]

Learn to use and read those as you get a feeling for what is possible.

### Service block

Second, you misunderstand the `Service` block. It does not have any such states. It is a combination of a `Seize`, `Queue`, `Delay` and `Release`.

There can be 1000 agents in the block, what does "busy" or "idle" mean then?

You can only have such KPIs on individual agents and resources that are actually busy or idle.

So either compute those yourself in the agent type or use the `ResourcePool` statistics that you get for free:
[image]

Comment: Hey Benjamin, thanks for the reply. 
My Problem is that somehow my ResourcePool is always busy when I combine the state with my Gantt-chart. So instead of being busy for the time a job spend in that service station, it shows me the whole time busy when I use Rp.

Comment: likely because your pool tracks several resources and one is always busy...